# what is the meaning of 'charge density transforms like a 0-component'?

Tags: special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry

I know a Lorentz scalar is invariant under lorentz transformations, but what exactly does this mean mathematically, $scalar'=\Lambda *scalar$? In particular, I dont know what this means for a charge $q$ to be Lorentz Invariant, and a mass $m$ not.

What is the correlation between Lorentz invariance and the charge density transforming like a 0-component of  of a Lorentz vector, and the mass density like a 00-tensor-component?

Comment: The quantity $m^2c^2$ is Lorentz invariant i.e., a Lorentz scalar. May I know which book are you reading? Are you familiar with the concept of a four-vector?

Comment: $c\rho$ is the $0^{th}$ component of the current density $j^\mu=(c\rho,\textbf{j})$.

Comment: I am working with lecture notes, which are mostly based on Weinberg, Gravitation and Cosmology,Wald, General Relativity, i think.

Comment: yes, but what does this (Lorentz invariant) mean written down mathematically? Thanks

Comment: $m^2c^2=p^\mu p_\mu$ where $p^\mu=(E/c,\textbf{p})$. It's the contraction of the contravariant $p^\mu$ with covariant $p_\mu$. Such contractions produce Lorentz scalars.